# ASP.NET 2 Gridviews share the same OnSelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have 2 Gridviews which share the same OnSelectedIndexChanged event.
How do I get the incoming Gridview the one which fired so that I can pass that GridView to DetailsView. In that DetailsView I need to access the selected Gridview columns.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "sender" parameter of the OnSelectedIndexChanged event should be the GridView that the event came from. You can get at it like this:

```
public void MyGrid_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView grid = sender as GridView;
    if (grid != null)
    {
        // Do something with grid
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

first parameter is "sender" as an object and you can cast it to a gridview object than check its ID.

GridView grd = (GridView) sender;